# Does android broadcast an event on completion of Bluetooth File Reception and if Yes, which is the Intent?

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to work with an android broadcast receiver, which i want to be invoked upon completion of BT file transfer (in case of receiving file).

Use Case :
Device (A) is already paired with another Bluetooth enabled device (B) and when B sends a file to device A, I want my broadcast receiver to execute.

***Is there any way to achieve it?***

I tried filtering for below events, but it seems to be private events of default **Bluetooth** app and is intented only for **BluetoothShare** component that pushes the notification on completion of file reception and **NOT** broadcasted publicly. As a result, my broadcast receiver is NOT invoked real device with actual file transfers but when I send any of the below intent from ADB shell its working in both emulator and real device.

Intents filtered in **AndroidManifest**.xml:

```
"android.btopp.intent.extra.**BT_OPP_TRANSFER_STATUS**"
"android.btopp.intent.action.**BT_OPP_TRANSFER_DONE**"
"android.intent.action.**DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE**"
```

Any leads would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Hi Prince, did you find any solution to that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor the Connectivity action of Bluetooth. There is a connecting action when the device begin to receive file and when its compeleted there will be a disconnecting action. You can register for `ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED` and `onReceive` take some action

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction() == BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED) {

        }
    }
}
```

Register receiver as follows:

```
IntentFileter blutoothFilter= new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);
this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, blutoothFilter);
```

Comment: Thanks Sagar for the input, does it happen only for file transfer or it will also be broadcast when device is using any other bluetooth profile ?

Also can't it be possible to get the intent broadcast by Bluetooth App in my app directly somehow ?

Comment: @PrinceRambade `does it happen only for file transfer or it will also be broadcast when device is using any other bluetooth profile ?` ACL: It is used exclusively to transport data. `Also can't it be possible to get the intent broadcast by Bluetooth App in my app directly somehow ?` No

Comment: Thanks @Sagar, 

I need the following : 
1) Bluetooth file download location and 
2) Downloaded file name ?

Does this information contained in ACL_DISCONNECTED intent by any chance ? if yes, how do we extract that info.
if No, then any other way to get that ?